# source code does not match the byte code android studio red sign

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, intellij-idea, bytecode

I'm developing an Android App using Android Studio v2.2, Gradle 2.14 and SDK build tools 24.0.2. My min supported SDK version is 15 (IceCreamSandwich) and I'm targeting SDK version 24. I'm developing on a Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505 with rooted Android 5.0.1. It doesn't matter what I do (reinstall the app on the device, clean project, rebuild project ), every time I debug into certain methods Android Studio makes a red sign appear saying "source code does not match the byte code". The only common pattern of all these methods I've been able to find is that they are all related to multithread execution (recording audio on one thread and processing it in another). I've selected the suspend all option instead of suspend thread option for my breakpoints when this happens. Does anyone have a clue about why is this happening? I've read that IntelliJ IDEA IDE had a bug somehow similar to this. Is this an Android Studio error?

Comment: I'm getting a similar message, and I've seen a few questions like this that were asked recently. I think this might have to do with the recent Android Studio update.

Comment: Hi @VMMF if you solved this could you share how?

Comment: @noelicus unfortunately I haven't yet